# How to split registration form into multiple pages without losing data in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My registration form requires a long scroll - what's the best way I can split this into maybe multiple pages? Anything I can use? And when I hit the next button to take user from page 1 to page 2 - will i lose the data they have entered in page 1? Any other implications?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Jquery Steps or Bootstrap Form Wizard with or without using AJAX.

http://www.jquery-steps.com/

https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Either you pass a Model from one Controller-Method to another or you save it to the TempData (you cannot use the ViewBag, because it will get reseted if you redirect from one controller to another).

Answer (score 0):

There are several different solutions to this type of problems.

You can use a client approach and just hide or show different parts of your form during user navigation through fields. You can also divide your form in different tabs or layers within the same page. With those approaches you don't need to change anything in your submission to server.

You can also look for a server approach. In that case, you can send your data through a chain of controllers - views loading your model object in the background with the info that is reaching your server with each petition.

In this case, for example, you show a view with your form's first page, when user pushes "next page" button you submit data to your server controller, register that data on your model object (without persisting to database yet, as your user hasn't completed it's petition and could want to go back) and redirect execution to a view where your form's second page is displayed.

Keep in mind that you'll need to maintain the information your user is submitting in each step stored somewhere, you can use a session variable, pass it from controller to view and back to controller in each step or use whatever other method that you want.